# How do I stack individual channels using Rust's image crate?

Tags: image, rust

**TL;DR:** What's the best way to create an RGB `GenericImage` out of 3 `View<&[u8], Luma<u8>>` for each RGB channel?

---

Consider the following code that gets a `width x height` buffer with a given `stride` for a single channel:

```rust
let ptr: *const u8 = ...pointer from ffi...;

let samples = std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, (stride*height) as usize);

let channels = 1;
let layout = image::flat::SampleLayout {
    width: width as u32,
    height: height as u32,
    channels: channels,
    width_stride: 1,
    height_stride: stride as usize,
    channel_stride: (stride*height) as usize,
};

let buffer = image::flat::FlatSamples {
    samples,
    layout,
    color_hint: None,
};

let view: View<&[u8], Luma<u8>> = buffer.as_view::<Luma<u8>>().unwrap();
```

I can get these independently from an external library for all RGB channels:

```rust
let views: [View<&[u8], Luma<u8>>; 3] = [view_r, view_g, view_b];
```

Is there a simple way to convert them into a `GenericImage`, other than manually using `get_pixel`/`put_pixel`?

Comment: `image::ImageBuffer` is structured as a single buffer of interleaved channels, so you will have to do some copying. That said, you can use [`from_fn`](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.from_fn) or [`pixels_mut`](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.pixels_mut) if you don't want to use `put_pixel`.

Comment: I thought there would be a quick shortcut for initializing a new `ImageBuffer` from a copy of channel views or for copying a single channel from a `View` into an existing empty `ImageBuffer`, as this seems to be a common operation. Apparently not ;)